# Using Sessions in Spring-MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

As I am new to spring MVC, I am stuck on this problem.
I am trying to use session Scope , where I want a list to be shared across multiple controller in a http session. But I do not want this session to be shared by different http sessions. Each http session should have its own list(storage) which is shared among its controllers.

The problem I am facing is , this list is shared among all the request which are running in parallel. 
For eg . If I hit the controller on my machine and some other request comes 
from a different machine ,they both are using the same list(session storage)

This is MySession class which holds a List which needs to be shared across multiple controllers and each controller can do operation on this list.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MySession
{
   public List<String> mylist;
}
```

Here is my controller which is using the MySession class object, Similarly there are other Controllers which can update the List in the session.

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class SessionController
{
   @Autowired
   private MySession mySession;

   @RequestMapping("/updateSession")
   public ModelAndView  updateSession(@RequestParam("id") int id)
   {
      //Operation on List(add remove items)
   }  
}
```

So now what is happening is List in MySession is getting effected my some other requests as I think all concurrent requests are using the same list.

Please help me how can I solve this problem if there is anything that I am missing
Ask for any modification.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the `MySession` list? I know you're probably not doing this, but as an example, if it was a static list you'd have this problem

Comment: No it is not static. Actually it is simple class object which contain java array list. Basically some session related information.

Comment: Yep. I'm saying it would be helpful if you could show a little more what `MySession` looks like

Comment: I have update mySession. It looks something like this.

Comment: Why is your controller even request scoped? That should be a singleton. Also what are you doing in the `updateSession` method?

Comment: I read here in this below link that controller must be request scoped otherwise the object will be globally shared. http://blog.chesterwood.io/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including-scoped-proxies.html

Comment: But even after doing this session object is getting shared globally